# How should I send information from a database to my App? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically, I am creating a very simple app, that will pop questions in the interface whenever the app receives a question, and then store the answer in the database (Yes, no, don’t know) something like this:

[App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFoyh.png)

**What I have done so far:**

I created my database using MySQL.

I created a script to get the information out of the database. (php script)

I created a very simple android studio user interface.

**My questions:**

1)  Just from reading on android.developer I can see that they use databases managed by SQLite, is there going to be a problem with my database being MySQL? Should I really consider redoing my database on SQLite?

2)  **My biggest issue** and what I am most ignorant about is how to send the information to the app. I have read and gotten feedback that I might want to use MQTT Mosquito as an open source to do this. Others say doing a REST Api, but I have also read about google firebase, and I want to know what is the simplest/easiest to learn method. Are there any recommended sample/methods from google that make this easy?

-Extra note on this point: have in mind that this is a simple app and I will have users registered to my app. (What I mean to registered to my app: I will have the phone numbers of the registered recipients in my database)

Here is a sample of how the information coming from the database looks so far:

[Database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kzWR.png)

3)  To send the data back to the database (Yes, no, don’t know) I started using the following code:
NOTE: obviuslly the if statements need to be filled, but I wanted to have some feedback on if I am implementing a good method.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButtonYes:
            if (checked)
                findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT).setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonNo:
            if (checked)
                findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT).setEnabled(true);
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonDontknow:
            if (checked)
                findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT).setEnabled(true);
                break;
    }
}
```

Thank you for anyone that would take the time to give me their opinion, I appreciate it.

Comment: what is you want to store to database? is different on local(device) and server? if you need to gather from, server API is right option, if no need with server database just use sqlite for local storage

Comment: 1. Since you aren't trying to install the database on the phone, it doesn't matter. 2. Shopping questions are off-topic for stackoverflow. 3. Opinion based questions are off-topic for stackoverflow. Consider coder review instead.